# Как использовать в родительских методах поля и свойства наследуемого класса?

Tags: c#, ооп, классы, наследование

Имеются два класса (родительский  дочерний соответственно):

```
class Unit
{
    protected string UnitChar = ".";

    public string Char
    {
        get => UnitChar;
    }

    public void Print() => Console.WriteLine(Char);
}


class Pawn : Unit
{
    protected new string UnitChar = "P";
}
```

В наследуемом классе я переопределяю поле `UnitChar`, присваивая ему строку `"P"`.
По моей задумке, метод и свойство, которые наследует `Pawn`, при вызове из его экземпляра должны использовать его поля и свойства, которые опираются на переопределенное поле.
Иными словами, наследуемый метод `Print` в классе `Pawn` должен использовать свойство `Char`, которое, в свою очередь возвращает переопределенный `UnitChar`.

Однако следующий код:

```
Unit U = new();
Pawn P = new();
U.Print();
P.Print();
Console.WriteLine($"{U.Char} {P.Char}");
```

Выводит:

```
.
.
. .
```

Хотя ожидается:

```
.
P
. P
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильнее (в соотвествии с задумкой автора) было бы сделать так:

```
class Unit {
    protected string UnitChar = ".";
    public string Char { get => UnitChar; }
    public void Print() => Console.WriteLine(Char);
}
class Pawn : Unit {
    public Pawn() :  base() { UnitChar = "P"; }
}
```

Объяснение в другом ответе. Я бы уточнил, что ключевое слово new "прячет" наследуемое поле и создаёт его новое определени (хотя оно и имеет такое же имя), которое будет использоваться не раньше (в иерархии наследования), чем в этом классе.

Comment: Спасибо, т.е, иными словами, поле, помеченное как new подменяет значение наследуемого поля для текущего класса и всего, что в нем происходит. Спасибо большое! До Вашего ответа тоже пришел к решению через конструктор, но никак не понимал, почему работает именно так. Мои спасители!

Answer (score 4):

```
class Unit
{
    public virtual string Char => ".";

    public void Print() => Console.WriteLine(Char);
}


class Pawn : Unit
{
    public override string Char => "P";
}
```

> В наследуемом классе я переопределяю поле UnitChar,

Нет. Переопределение происходит только при наличии ключевого слова `override`. Тогда в методе `Print` при доступе к свойству `Char` рантайм будет вызывать его как виртуальный метод и проверять таблицу с типами, чтобы определить какой именно нужно вызвать метод, оригинальный или из наследника.

А ключевого слова `new` просто "прячет" оригинальный метод и предоставляет новую реализацию (хотя она и имеет такое же имя), которая будет вызываться только тогда, когда на этапе компиляции компилятор определил, что идет именно доступ к этой "версии" метода.

Например, если в вашей версии кода выполнить `new Pawn().UnitChar` (предположим что оно `public`), то оно, как и ожидалось, вернет `P` вместо `.`.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Хотелось бы и Ваш, и верхний лучшими отметить)